# "Waiting for /dev to be fully populated" takes long after upgrading to Debian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot, boot-issues, raspbian-jessie

I just upgraded my RPi B from `wheezy` to `jessie`. This worked fine so far. Only had some trouble with `systemd`, so I uninstalled it and switched back to `sysvinit` (I like it more anyways). Now I am on `jessie`, everything works as before, with one small but annoying difference:

The boot process takes around 20 to 30 seconds *additionally* (before it was like 10 seconds all together) on the step

```
Waiting for /dev to be fully populated
```

It switches to `OK` in the end and everything works, but since `jessie` it takes horribly long to succeed.

Additional information:

- The Pi is running headless (SSH only, no display)
- no USB device is attached (no WiFi dongle, no keyboard, no HDD, no whatsoever)
- only the default stuff is mounted (SD card)

After googling a while I found out that it seems that `/etc/udev` is responsible for that, but I'm not sure what I have to look for. Especially, the config files in there are empty or "trivial" one-liners which I manually never touched (so I assume they are in the default state).

**What device could cause this long pause on a plain Raspberry Pi? And how to speed it up again?**

Comment: Did you have this problem *before* you switched back to SysV init?

Comment: @goldilocks Not sure. With systemd the boot was extremly slow anyways on several steps, it always bootet into emergency mode (for which I plugged a display and keyboard on, and uninstalled systemd, then removed display and keyboard again). I can't say if systemd was slow on this step as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Raspbian Jessie and I solved it like this:

Edit /etc/udev/udev.conf and change from:

```
udev_log="info"
```

to

```
udev_log="err"
```

Worked for me.